# RichTextBox appearance

Tags: winforms

I am showing some text on RichTextBox in a winform. But I dont want the user to interact with it. Even after setting it Read Only, I can still see the cursor blinking inside it. If I disable it, the text gets faded which I dont want. Any idea how can I make it work or any work around. I am using RichTextbox because I need multilines and I need to show the borders around it. And its size is fixed.

Comment: Note that a standard Textbox has a Multiline property, so needing multilines alone shouldn't be a reason to use a rich text box.

Comment: I can't use textbox because if you set it readonly you can still see the cursor blinking inside.....If you disable it, the text is faded.

Comment: I understand that a textbox has the same focus issue; I'm just clarifying that the reason that you need to use a rich textbox is something other than the need for multiline support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the following properties on your RichTextBox

```
Enabled  = false
ReadOnly = true
ForeColor = #000001 // From code, say = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 1)
```

The "trick" is setting the `ForeColor` to something that isn't quite black (`#000000`); if you do that then the text won't come out as gray when the `RichTextBox` is disabled.

Comment: To change BackColor add a Panel control as holder of transparent RichTextLabel

Answer (score -1):

In the Enter event of the textbox, focus another control.